# Rails Schedule job from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

Question: This is the code in my `schedule.rb` file.
Is there any appropiate way to edit `'* * 1 * *'` this code by MVC.
Am new on RoR... Thanks in advance.

```
every '* * 1 * *' do
  runner 'MonthlyMailJob.perform_later'
end
```

This is my schedule.rb

Answer (score 2):

For customizing job scheduling you can use [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job).